# Component is not showing

Tags: reactjs, redux

Component is not showing. I don't get any error messages. I am trying to fetch data from a url and build a simple list on PollList from that data. I can console.log(polls) from the action and it works but it just doesn't build the list

Here is the code.

pollsactions.js

```
import { GET_POLLS, POLLS_LOADING } from './types';


export const getPolls = () => dispatch => {
    return fetch(URL)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(polls => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_POLLS,
                payload: polls
            })
        })

}
```

pollsreducers.js

```
import {
    GET_POLLS,
    POLLS_LOADING
} from '../actions/types';



const pollReducer = (state = [], { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case GET_POLLS:
            return payload
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default pollReducer;
```

PollList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getPolls } from '../redux/actions/pollsActions';

class PollList extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getPolls();
    }

    render() {
        const { polls } = this.props.polls

        return (

            <div>
                {
                    polls && polls.map((poll) => (
                        <div key={poll.id}>

                            {(poll.type)}

                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>

        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    polls: state.polls
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getPolls }
)(PollList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are destructuring `polls` incorrectly. `polls` is on `this.props` based on your `mapStateToProps()`, not on `this.props.polls`. Try changing:

```
const { polls } = this.props.polls;
```

to:

```
const { polls } = this.props;
```

Otherwise, without destructuring, it would look like:

```
const polls = this.props.polls;
```

Hopefully that helps!